# How to add a product to the cart using a URL or query string?

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, cart, url

I'm using Magento Enterprise 1.13; there appears to be some documentation around for adding a product using the URL & query string but those do not appear to be working for me.

For example:

[Add Configurable Product To Cart Via Query String In 1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/add-configurable-product-to-cart-via-query-string-in-1-7)

Is there a different or documented methodology for doing this now?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

My answer is based on the assumption that EE-1.13 is similar to CE 1.8.
Starting CE 1.8 there is a form key validation on the add to cart action.
`Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction` starts with this:

```
if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
    $this->_goBack();
    return;
}
```

The method is defined in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`

```
protected function _validateFormKey()
{
    if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null))
        || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This means that if you don't send a valid request parameter named `form_key` with the value stored in the current session the add to cart won't work. it won't work.
So, you have to append to the url the session form key value.
If you are planning to have this link from an "outside" page then you have a problem because you cannot access the session key.

Comment: Ah yes I do plan on linking from outside. Do I need to create a special front controller that redirects with the form key?

Comment: I think it is a good approach. You can pass through a proxy controller in order to get the session form key.

Comment: Any information on how to to create that front controller? I also need to provide linking from outside my website. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a product to cart using query string/url by following code:

http://yourstoreurl/checkout/cart/add/product/[id]/qty/[qty]
example : http://example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/2880/qty/2

or

http://yourstoreurl/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
example : http://example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=2880&qty=2

Comment: This work for simplest simple product, what's about custom option or configurable/grouped items ?

Comment: Simple product with custom options:
http://yourstoreurl/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]&options[option_id]=[selection_id]
http://example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=2880&qty=2&options[64]=10

Configurational products: 
http://yourstoreurl/checkout/cart/add/product/126?super_attribute[attribute_id]=option_id&super_attribute[attribute_id]=option_id
http://example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/2880?super_attribute[150]=10&super_attribute[151]=12

Bundle products:
http://yourstoreurl/checkout/cart/add/product/[id]/?bundle_option[[option_id]][]=[selection_id]

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore as Magento now requires a form key to be sent along with the request. See the answer above.