# Add to Cart via URL/Query String in CE 1.7

Tags: cart, checkout, url, query

I'm having an issue creating a query string that will allow me to add a product to the users cart. I've followed the steps mentioned in [this exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/add-configurable-product-to-cart-via-query-string-in-1-7/5422#5422?newreg=6cf900f05b7845d9b6cb3b4711815a2e) and still can't get it to work. I've been using this link to try and add the configurable product:

```
http://example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/6184?super_attribute[179]=7927
```

The configurable product ID is **6184**, the supper attribute (format) is **179** and the product ID **7927**.

I just want to have a link in an email blast that, once clicked, the customer will automatically have the item added to their cart. Am I doing something wrong? I've read in some places that Magento no longer supports this standard query any more. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

The super_attribute part of the url should be as follows:

```
super_attribute[attribute_id]=attribute_option_value
```

In you question you say you used the product id but it should not be the product id but the attribute value selected of the simple product.

Comment: Thanks David! Where would I find the "attribute value selected of the simple product."

Comment: How are the options shown on the page?

Comment: On the back end or front end?

Comment: On the Front end side

Comment: It's a configurable product, the customer hits "choose an option" and is given three options: an MP3, MP4, or CD.